# Curl request failing (times out)

Tags: php, curl, https, kml

I have been requesting a kml file via cron job from a https nasa.gov site. It has worked for years and just now started failing. I don't get any curl errors- the request just times out. Something must have changed with the nasa site.

```
$curl_connection = 
  curl_init("http://firms.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/active_fire/kml/USA_contiguous_and_Hawaii_24h.kml");

//set options
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 
  "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt( $curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

//perform our request
$string = curl_exec($curl_connection);

//show information regarding the request
print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));
echo curl_errno($curl_connection) . '-' . 
curl_error($curl_connection);

//close the connection
curl_close($curl_connection);
```

Comment: if you have done nothing, then perhaps nasa has, ask them\

Answer (score 0):

> Something must have changed with the nasa site.

It looks like they are using HTTPS now:

```
$ curl http://firms.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/active_fire/kml/USA_contiguous_and_Hawaii_24h.kml
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://firms.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/active_fire/kml/USA_contiguous_and_Hawaii_24h.kml">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

You consumed that data all those years without authenticity assurances :)

This might be useful for you: [How do I tell curl to follow HTTP redirects?](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#How_do_I_tell_curl_to_follow_HTT).

The URL may have changed, too. But that's an exercise left to the reader.